# Como puedo ubicar donde yo quiera una lista?

Tags: android, lista, flutter, ios, dart

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('CRUD'),
          ),
          drawer: menu_drawer(),//Barra lateral
          body: Container(
            child: FutureBuilder<List> (
              future: obtenerCC(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if(snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
                return snapshot.hasData
                    ? ElementoLista(
                  lista: snapshot.data!,
                )
                    : Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              },

            ),
          ),

        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

> el elementolista me trae el arreglo de mi lista, al validar base de
> datos y mostrar resultado.

> Ahora busco poder ubicar esa lista mas abajo para poner información
> estática arriba o abajo.

> Ya intente meterlo en Columna , Wrap para poder tener mas elementos en
> su interior.

> Pero cuando hago esto la lista no aparece en pantalla.

> Esta es mi clase Elementolista la cual estoy mostrando arriba

```
class ElementoLista extends StatelessWidget {

  final List lista;

  ElementoLista({ required this.lista });


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: lista == null ? 0 : lista.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, posicion) {
        return Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: Card(
              color: Colors.deepPurple,
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Text(
                  "Nombre cliente: "+lista[posicion]['nom_cli']+" "+
                      lista[posicion]['ape_cli']+"\n "+
                      "CC: "+lista[posicion]['documento'],
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),

          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

> Debo de poner varias listas, en distintos sentidos, que se desplacen
> de izquierda a derecha y de arriba a abajo, pensaba hacerlo metiendo
> en filas, columnas pero automáticamente mi lista desaparece y mi
> pantalla se queda en blanco.

Comment: Cuál es el error que te arroja la consola?

Comment: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#a01a4 relayoutBoundary=up2 NEEDS-PAINT
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 2001 pos 12: 'hasSize'

Comment: El error creo que se da porque Flutter no es capaz de calcular cuánto espacio necesita la lista y/o los hijos de ellas. ¿Dónde estás usando el widget que contiene el scaffold?

Answer (score 0):

Debes darle un espacio a tu listView.builder para que se dibuje correctamente, encierra el contenido en una Colummna y a ListView.Builder encierralo en un Expanded, esto hará que la lista ocupe el resto de la pantalla para poder dibujarse, mientras que el contenido que quieras mostrar estáticamente ocupara el espacio necesario:

```
Column(
 children: [
    //aqui tu widget estático
    Container(child: Text("Hola mundo")),
    //aqui el expanded
    Expanded(
         child: ElementoLista(
            lista: snapshot.data!,
        ),
      )
   ]
)
```